# Get object from <select> using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a "select" on my JSP. It is fill by "Region" objects like this :

```html
<sf:select id="regionslist" path="region" items="${regions}" itemLabel="nameRegion"/>
```

I want to get the attribute "Region.idRegion" from the selected one on my list.

Using this script :

```js
$regions.on('change',
      function(){
       var val = $('#regionslist option:selected').val();
       console.log(val)
            }
)
```

i retrieve the object reference not the object in it self (mypackage.Entity.Region@75448e27).

I heare about the possibility to use a JSON parser to get the object on the JS script but i'm newbee concerning JS. So can samone help me ?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide a resulting html?

Answer (score 0):

Lets pretend you got the following HTML:

```
<select name="my-select" id="my-select">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4" selected>4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
</select>

<button id="my-button">Get selected value</button>
```

And this is the JS to get the value of the selected option:

```
var form = document.getElementById('my-select'),
    button = document.getElementById('my-button');

button.onclick = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log(form.value);
}
```

And here you can see a live demo. http://jsfiddle.net/yck69tLb/

Comment: Thank you for answer, but you did exactly what  i do. Just writtent in different way :)